# What is the legality of police wielding obscurantist legal sophistry against the public?

Tags: england-and-wales, police, human-rights, deception, victims-rights

Alice is at a protest and gets into an altercation with another group. She shouts various lawful slogans towards them, and they report her to the police who arrive, seeking to “deescalate” the situation even while no crimes have even arguably been committed. The police try to persuade the two groups to go in separate directions, lest anyone would like to be arrested that day.

Alice challenges Officer Connor’s bluff, questioning whether, for someone to be arrested, they mustn’t first commit some criminal offence. Connor replies, no, cause if other people are offended by your chanting then there would be a “breach of the peace.”

Not knowing what this is, Alice capitulated and backs down from exercising her article 10 rights when the police rightly had no power to insist she stop, and it seems that their priorities should be firstly upholding and defending everyone’s human rights including by not dissuading them from exercising them through deception, and then, if not in conflict with the former, encouraging them to take courses of action that may be wise as far as avoiding unsafe situations on a precautionary basis.

What implications or consequences does such misleading sophistry designed to deter the public from either exercising their fundamental rights, or from legitimately pursuing the services of the police, perhaps in hopes that they will not be dismissed by lazy sophistic excuses?

If it transpired in the case of deterring the public from exercising their fundamental convention rights, then would it just give a cause of civil action under the human rights act?

Or would there be a more immediate or direct implication/remedy? Regardless, is there anything proscribing the police from behaving in such legally misleading manners?

Comment: I'm confused... what do Constance and Alice have in common? What is your question really about?

Comment: Are you asking if there is law to prevent a police officer from deliberately or inadvertently misleading a member of the public about the law?

Comment: @nvoigt nothing; Constance misled Bob, Connor misled Alice: both used obscurantist sophistry to mislead/deceive the public about their interests and rights.

Comment: @Lag yes, I suppose I am asking something like that. Though my question would include also whether it’s okay to mislead the public by encouraging them through stern and tonally threatening words of advice to cease exercising fundamental rights in the interest of avoiding dangerous conflict for example (whether such misleading makes any false legal claims like “civil matter” or not) thereby effectively putting the police’s interest in maintaining the public’s physical safety above that of upholding and protecting their fundamental rights.

Comment: And also what remedies may exist in any case.

Comment: I don't understand. If no false claims are made I don't see what is misleading about encouraging members of the public to avoid "dangerous conflict". With the exception of prohibition of torture, our rights may be lawfully interfered with - particularly when the exercise of our rights has the consequence of disorder or violence. If a person believes the police unlawfully arrested or detained the person, or unlawfully interfered with the person's rights, then the person can make a formal complaint or bring legal proceedings against the police.

Comment: There is irony in your use of the word "sophistry"...

Comment: @MichaelHall feel free to explain what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

Police can issue [“move on” orders](http://www5.austlii.edu.au/au/legis/nsw/consol_act/leara2002451/s197.html) in certain circumstances. Failing to obey a lawfully issued “move on” order is an offence.

Officer Connor can certainly inform Alice that they are considering exercising that power against Alice.

Answer (score 0):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Short of lying about a person's right to remain silent (when it exists), or the right to a lawyer (when it exists), or the fact of one's detention, police are allowed to lie about the law and one's potential jeopardy.